# Retrieve additional rows if bit flag is true

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a large stored procedure that is used to return results for a dialog with many selections. I have a new criteria to get "extra" rows if a particular bit column is set to true. The current setup looks like this:

```
SELECT
  CustomerID,
  FirstName,
  LastName,
  ...
FROM HumongousQuery hq
LEFT JOIN (
    -- New Query Text
) newSubQuery nsq ON hq.CustomerID = nsq.CustomerID
```

I have the first half of the new query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    c.CustomerID,
    pp.ProjectID,
    ep.ProductID
FROM Customers c
JOIN Evaluations e (NOLOCK)
    ON c.CustomerID = e.CustomerID
JOIN EvaluationProducts ep (NOLOCK)
    ON e.EvaluationID = ep.EvaluationID
JOIN ProjectProducts pp (NOLOCK)
    ON ep.ProductID = pp.ProductID
JOIN Projects p
    ON pp.ProjectID = p.ProjectID
WHERE 
    c.EmployeeID = @EmployeeID
    AND e.CurrentStepID = 5
    AND p.IsComplete = 0
```

The Projects table has a bit column, AllowIndirectCustomers, which tells me that this project can use additional customers when the value is true. As far as I can tell, the majority of the different SQL constructs are geared towards adding additional columns to the result set. I tried different permutations of the UNION command, with no luck. Normally, I would turn to a table-valued function, but I haven't been able to make it work with this scenerio.

This one has been a stumper for me. Any ideas?

Comment: How do you determine if the customer is to be included?  Both when you allow indirect and when you don't.

Comment: The query above is for direct assignments to a specific employee. This one is used regardless of the bit flag. Basically, indirects are customers that are assigned to the employee, have the same product, but are in a different project.

Comment: Check below and let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Alright, going to try that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So basically, you're looking to negate the need to match `pp.ProjectID = p.ProjectID` when the flag is set.  You can do that right in the `JOIN` criteria:

```
JOIN Projects p
    ON pp.ProjectID = p.ProjectID OR p.AllowIndirectCustomers = 1
```

Comment: Holy Edge Case, Batman! Didn't know you could do that with an OR in the JOIN. Learnt something new today. :)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the complexity of your tables, this might not work out too easily, but you could do a `case` statement on your `bit` column. Something like this:

```
select table1.id, table1.value, 
case table1.flag 
    when 1 then 
        table2.value
    else null
end as secondvalue
from table1
left join table2 on table1.id = table2.id
```

Here's a [SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/59979/2)

Comment: I kinda wanna give you a +1 just for your username.  But it sounds like the OP is looking to add rows rather than change the value of rows he already has.